# Where could my cronjobs have gone?

Tags: debian, cron

I am running a small Raspbian (Debian) NAS.
A week ago I wrote some single line cronjobs.
However, when I now look at `crontab -l` for `root` or my user, I get: `no crontab for [user]`.

So, where could my cronjobs be? I did upgrade my system yesterday. Does this usually overwrite crontabs?

I did not make any other system changes in the mean time.

Comment: How did you set the jobs up? System-wide crontab (`/etc/crontab` and related) is something different than any user's crontab. Did you use it maybe?

Comment: In addition to @KamilMaciorowski: how did you upgrade the system? If you unpacked a new raspian to the SD card, then you overwrote the crontabs. You could also look under `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`.

Comment: They're not in `/etc/crontab`. 
And what I did were simple `update` & `upgrade` of packages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already checked if maybe yesterday you ran `crontab` as another user? All users of your machine have different crontabs, but always if you write:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

You will see root's crontab. Check the crontabs of other users by typing only `crontab -e` without `sudo`.

Comment: I only have my `pi` (default) user and `root` users. I believe `root` is the same as `sudo crontab`.